# How to add tooltips with boostrap and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assets

My mates and I are working on a website using Ruby on Rails.
We managed to plug a bootstrap theme called [Boomerang](http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB021609D).
I think I kind of figured out our assets work but I have an error that I can't understand.

In the footer there are socials icons with tooltips that should be displayed when you hover them. But they are not displayed.Here is the HTML code I use to display the icons:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/webpixels/" class="facebook" target="_blank" 
  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement='top' title='title' 
  data-original-title="Facebook">
  <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
</a>
```

In the console I see an error:

> Error: TOOLTIP: Option "placement" provided type "undefined" but expected type "(string|function)". bootstrap.min.self-bb6761dcfa4675bf8423f8365beedf711cfb74e526bdc84b575d7024f1772e5b.js:7:2581
>       typeCheckConfig http://localhost:3000/assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.self-bb6761dcfa4675bf8423f8365beedf711cfb74e526bdc84b575d7024f1772e5b.js?body=1:7
>       _getConfig http://localhost:3000/assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.self-bb6761dcfa4675bf8423f8365beedf711cfb74e526bdc84b575d7024f1772e5b.js?body=1:7
>       i http://localhost:3000/assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.self-bb6761dcfa4675bf8423f8365beedf711cfb74e526bdc84b575d7024f1772e5b.js?body=1:7
>       _jQueryInterface http://localhost:3000/assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.self-bb6761dcfa4675bf8423f8365beedf711cfb74e526bdc84b575d7024f1772e5b.js?body=1:7
>       jQuery 2
>       _jQueryInterface http://localhost:3000/assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.self-bb6761dcfa4675bf8423f8365beedf711cfb74e526bdc84b575d7024f1772e5b.js?body=1:7
>        http://localhost:3000/assets/boomerang.self-e1e63791e18eaede171d51277b9a09fe35d859c9a0314d67c65f3765dad80563.js?body=1:900
>       jQuery 2

It seems that the error is coming from one file (bootstrap.min.js) so I tried to link the full file instead (bootstrap.js) and then the error changed to:

> Error: TOOLTIP: Option "placement" provided type "undefined" but expected type "(string|function)". util.js:142:11 
>       typeCheckConfig util.js:142
>       _getConfig tooltip.js:638
>       Tooltip tooltip.js:130
>       _jQueryInterface tooltip.js:694
>       jQuery 2
>       _jQueryInterface tooltip.js:685
>        boomerang.self-e1e63791e18eaede171d51277b9a09fe35d859c9a0314d67c65f3765dad80563.js:900
>       jQuery 2

It seems like another file is responsible for my error but I don't understand why. I've thought maybe there is a problem with the order the js files are actually loaded.

My javascript.js manifest file looks like :

```
//= require jquery/jquery.min
//= require popper/popper.min
//= require bootstrap/js/bootstrap
//= require slidebar/slidebar
//= require classie
//= require bootstrap-notify/bootstrap-growl.min
//= require scrollpos-styler/scrollpos-styler
//= require adaptive-backgrounds/adaptive-backgrounds
//= require countdown/js/jquery.countdown.min
//= require dropzone/dropzone.min
//= require easy-pie-chart/jquery.easypiechart.min
//= require fancybox/js/jquery.fancybox.min
//= require flatpickr/flatpickr.min
//= require flip/flip.min
//= require footer-reveal/footer-reveal.min
//= require gradientify/jquery.gradientify.min
//= require headroom/headroom.min
//= require headroom/jquery.headroom.min
//= require input-mask/input-mask.min
//= require instafeed/instafeed
//= require milestone-counter/jquery.countTo
//= require nouislider/js/nouislider.min
//= require paraxify/paraxify.min
//= require select2/js/select2.min
//= require sticky-kit/sticky-kit.min
//= require swiper/js/swiper.min
//= require textarea-autosize/autosize.min
//= require typeahead/typeahead.bundle.min
//= require typed/typed.min
//= require vide/vide.min
//= require viewport-checker/viewportchecker.min
//= require wow/wow.min
//= require isotope/isotope.min
//= require imagesloaded/imagesloaded.pkgd.min
//= require boomerang
```

The error only happens when I put an HTML tag with the data-toggle="tooltip" whether I put a data-placement in it or not.

I have the same issue when I load the original template/theme locally without touching anything

If you ever encountered this issue please help.

As suggested by a comment that suddenly disappeared I tried adding

```
$(function(){
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 
});
```

I noticed an error in the browser console ($ is not defined), I figured out jquery wasn't plugged in properly. Now jquery seems to be working, but still no cool tooltips.

Comment: You have a lot of required scripts, one of them could override the data-tooltip

Comment: I think bootstrap depends on jquery3, but you are using jquery2, try removing the extra scripts and add jquery3(should be on top, followed by bootstrap and then poper), also the code added on your 'EDIT' is required, you need to call tooltip() on the objects that you want to have it, if that fixes your problem, check if you have compatibility with the dependencies of the rest of your scripts